# trying to hide or not show the word "Submit"

Tags: html, css

I have a html button, and i have added a background image to it that has the a word "SUBMIT" the problem is that on top of the image there is a "Submit" that i cant get rid off.

Here is my code

```
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />

      .button{
      background: white url('../images/mybtn.png') no-repeat top;
      width: 150px;
      height: 30px;
}
```

How can i get rid of the default "Submit" on the button?

Thank you

Comment: you can just put the value as empty string ""

Comment: Don't hide content in your background images. If you want an image for a button then use `<button type="submit"><img src="..." alt="..."></button>` or an `<input type="image">`.

Comment: it is not exactly content. Its a button text, and he wants to use an image with the same text. May be he wants to stick to a submit button because of some other advantages that he may have from a submit button.

Comment: @Ashley — It tells people what the button does so it is exactly content. If he wants to use an image then HTML provides two different mechanisms to do so. Breaking accessibility by concealing actual content and using a decorative image to replace it is wrong, no matter what other advantages might be floating around.

Comment: I totally agree with what you are saying, accessibility is indeed an important thing and I did not think of it.. maybe because I mostly build for corporate intranet and they are not that big on accessibility sadly. In certain frameworks (struts/springmvc ??) a submit button would give you a lot of power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write `text-indent:-9999px` in your button like this:

```
.button{
      background: white url('../images/mybtn.png') no-repeat top;
      width: 150px;
      height: 30px;
      text-indent:-9999px;
      overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image as an input type which will work as a submit button, as shown by [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: he wants to achieve it with a submit button and it is possible with a submit button so why propose alternatives. There may be a lot of advantages of using a submit button from the overall application framework's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`value="Submit"`
to
`value="" name="Submit"`

Answer (score 0):

why not just state value=""? Or set button's css like this :-

```
.button {
text-indent: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

This will hide the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

juz dont mention anything like value="something"... or else use text-indent to place the text "value" that appears to somewhere that becomes invisible for the window.....

Answer (score 0):

set the value to empty

```
<input type="submit" class="subbut" value="" />
```